# vue3 multi language site, possible side effects with computed properties, dynamic components,

Tags: vuex, vue-router, vuejs3, computed-properties, vue-dynamic-components

I display the header and footer of a website with the help of vuex + vue-router + dynamic components.
I fetch the current routes from vue-router via vuex and "inject" the data into App.vue, where I have my header and footer. I can console.log the correct routes of every page.

The app.vue markup looks like that:

```
<component :is="selectedHeader"></component>
   <router-view></router-view>
<component :is="selectedFooter"></component>
```

Now I use the computed properties selectedFooter and selectedHeader in order to display the correct components:

```
  computed: {
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/return-in-computed-property
    selectedHeader() {    
      // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
      this.currentRoute = this.$store.getters.getRoute
     
      if(this.currentRoute) {

      if(this.currentRoute.includes("de")) {          
          return "de-header";     
      }

      if(this.currentRoute.includes("en")) {
          return "en-header";
      }

      if(this.currentRoute.includes("es")) {          
          return "es-header";     
      }

      
    }},

    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/return-in-computed-property
    selectedFooter() {
         // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
         this.currentRoute = this.$store.getters.getRoute
     
      if(this.currentRoute) {

       if(this.currentRoute.includes("de")) {          
          return "de-footer";     
      }  

      if(this.currentRoute.includes("en")) {
          return "en-footer";
      }

      else if(this.currentRoute.includes("es")) {          
          return "es-footer";     
      }
     
    }},
```

It pricipally works, but I think that I'm already experiencing side effects because I don't use the computed properties correctly, e.g. one route displays to the wrong language header, even though the route data from the store is definitely correct?

I guess that it would be better to use watchers, but how?

Comment: Without an MCVE (see [mcve]), it's difficult to see what's wrong with your approach. You don't need to use watchers in this case, since the return value of your computed's will be updated when the value(s) of their dependencies change (in this case, the value of `this.$store.getters.getRoute`.

Comment: As I said the routes this.$store.getters.getRoute are always correct, I can console.log them within the computed properties. Displaying the wrong header/footer (only for one route) differs from the order of the if-statements in selectedHeader() and selectedFooter(). This is why I thought that ESLint warns me about side effects.